# how to change background color in android app

Tags: android, xml, colors

I am currently developing an android app and I want to change the background color of a particular xml file to green. I have two xml files. One is the main activity file and the other one is the second activity file. I want to change the background color of the second `activity.xml`. I tried using the `android:background="#008A00"`. the visual editor displays the green color but my problem is that when I run my app in the emulator it still displays the default color(which is black in my case). I also created a `color.xml` in the values folder and defined the color. 
This is my code in the `color.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="green">#008A00</color>
</resources>
```

and I also tried changing the `android:background="#008A00"` to this:

```
android:background="@color/green"
```

but still the emulator displays the black color. Please help

Comment: Could you post some code ? (Activities/Layouts)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the {Relative, Absolute, Linear} Layout android:background attribute not others with the same:

```
android:background="#008A00"
```

Just in the xml file you wish your interface color to be.

Comment: I tried it but the graphical editor shows the color change but the emulator is not displaying it. I tried it by changing the layout to Linear,Absolute,Relative but still it is not working.I don't know what is wrong.I even tried using @drawable but still it wont work. I am clueless. Please help